# how to add single quote inside the php when passing argument for onclick javascript function?

Tags: php

Anyone know how should I write to get long hash value inside the single quote but when writing this code inside the php.

For example at the moment my code is below which I know its wrong:

```
$raw_tbody .= "<td width='10%'><a onclick='customRuleEdit('{$row['hash']}')' >";
```

So when I write like above its display on HTML side like below: (Which is wrong as you can see the single and double quotes)

```
<a onclick="customRuleEdit(" f6710ecaa686546bb424525686c792823f8d5193')'="">
```

What I want is as below Output:

```
<a onclick="customRuleEdit('f6710ecaa686546bb424525686c792823f8d5193')">
```

So anyone knows what I should write to make the output like above??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this code for helpful.. 

 $raw_tbody .= "<td width='10%'><a onclick=\"customRuleEdit('{$row['hash']}')\" >";
```

Comment: Thanks, Bro, that's work and it's really small but useful and I did resolve earlier but I completly forgot what I have done to fix it in some other project.

Comment: @Jimil Welcome Bro.